# Nivo Slider restart to slide 1

Tags: reset, restart, nivo-slider

Is there a way to make the Nivo Slider go back to the first slide manually?
So that if I press a button it will restart the slider from the beginning.
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you're using the jQuery version refer to this http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/

You want to set `controlNav: true` then you will get the page selection like the demo on their page.

If you *ONLY* want to give them an option to return to slide 0 and not pick each one individually then you'll have to modify the slider since there is no default behavior that supports that.

Comment: The link you provided is reoved. can you show code for this. @bbedward

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to modify the slider...

```
    var idx = 0; // '0' is the first slide

    // set nivo's currentSlide var to one before the idx value
    $('#slider').data('nivo:vars').currentSlide = idx - 1;

    // trigger a nextNav click
    $("#slider a.nivo-nextNav").trigger('click'); // trigger a click on the nextNav
```